# IIS 7 w/ MVC 3 Permissions Issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, iis-7, permissions

I currently am in the process of deploying a MVC 3 Web App to an IIS 7 server.  When I work on the web app from visual studio and deploy through development server, the web app has no problem using a custom .dll that interacts with a local server.  However, when I deploy onto IIS 7, the same dll fails to pull data from the server through the dll.  I am assuming this is permissions related.  I have assigned the AppPool to use an account I created that is a member of the local 'Adminstrators' account.  No Success.  My account is a member of this group.   One quirk I noticed was when I tried to modify security setting in the %WINDIR%\inetsvr folder, which holds the process that runs web server for IIS, I was unable to modify these setting even tho I am a member of the 'administrator' account.  Confused about this, and have been running around in circles trying to figure this one out.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What precisely is this DLL trying to do on the server? Access some files?

Comment: Its an API for a server service for a multidimensional database package.  I have been used process explorer to verify that the server (both development and IIS ) are picking up same instances of the dll in the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

Your web app's associated user definitely don't need to have access permission to `%WINDIR%\inetsvr`.

Assuming that your website runs on `C:\interpub\myWebsite` and `.Net 4.0`, your web app's user needs to have at least reader access to following folders :

> - C:\interpub\myWebsite
> - %windir%\Microsoft.NET\FrameWork\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

If you don't grant those access to those folder then it is so likely that your app won't run.

Also, visit your site with a browser inside your production server and see the detailed IIS error. That might help to narrow the problem down.

> **NOTE**
>
> Also, be sure that your app pool is in integrated mode because ASP.NET
>   MVC won't work properly under classic mode if you have extensionless
>   Urls. It is highly likely that you will get 404.

Comment: My app seems to run fine, except for one functional part doesn't work.  It is definitely connected directly to a dll I created in .NET 2.0, which was built on an API built on 2.0.  For some reason this dll performs functionally on the development server, but when I run it from IIS the dll does not perform its job as expected.  I have tried signing the dll under question, and still no success.  But as for your issues above, I have no problems with the site running from IIS, it is mostly related to one DLL.